# can't get popeasy jquery modal lightbox plugin to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

So, after looking at many jquery modal plugins, I like the PopEasy ( http://thomasgrauer.com/popeasy/ ), but I copy and paste the provided code into a page on my server and no-workey.

Do the same with jsFiddle, same problem. The overlay fires, but the modal doesn't pop up. I'm sure that I'm doing one simple thing wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/birchy/Kkw2L/5/

```
<a class="modalLink" href="#">Click Me
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="modal">
<a href="#" class="closeBtn">Close Me</a>
content here
</div>
```

Comment: wow, first time I've asked a question and haven't at least got a snotty comment... must be really busy here, or the question is too hard/complicated?

Comment: Stumbled on a claim that PopEasy uses depreciated jquery functions. I've tried running it with 1.6.4, the oldest available on jsFiddle, so if that is the problem, it must be over 3 yrs old. You would think the author would take his site down by now if it hasn't worked for three years.

Comment: I just noticed that the first anchor isn't closed. It isn't closed in the author's sample. Closing it didn't help, but then after flailing around, I think maybe it did.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a missing anchor close tag in the author's code.